# Stop error list from showing up at each compilation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I have the error list window showing up each time I compile my solution (with a lot of errors) and I'd like to stop it and deal with the output window directly.

I used the previous versions of visual studio for years without having this kind of problem before. Of course, I unchecked the option for the error list to automatically appear at the end of the compilation :

[image]

But no luck the behavior is still happening.

I'm not sure if it has a link, but the solution has been created from Unity 5.

I know it's not a very big deal, but I'm used to work with the output window, it shows a lot more errors at a time than the error list and I have to deal with a very large number of errors and I find it more readable. I bore it for several days now, but it's making me crazy.

Comment: Then why don't you just undock the error list, resize it to minimum and place it in a corner of the active window.

Comment: That's a much more constructive answer, I simply didn't think of it. It's much better with your workaround, but still gets focus sometimes (looks random) after a few errors got fixed.